# Google rich snippets not showing in SERP but was detected in Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google, rich-snippets

My rich snippets don't show in Google SERPs but Google Webmaster Tools detected that I have  more than 2 thousand pages that shows my rich snippets. I can see the snippets at Google rich snippets testing tool, everything is fine there.

What are the possible reasons why it happens?

Comment: How long has it been since you have implemented, and if you view a google chach of the page, does it have the current page cached with the markup in the source code? If not you may need to wait until Google cache the page with the changes.

Comment: I implemented it last June 4. It was showing on [Google Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=www.cebujobs.ph) please take a look. I can also see the code in Google cache(Im sure it was indexed). I used Structured Data Markup Helper to make everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Rich snippets will not always show up in the SERP. I believe it has something to do with the amount of traffic to a given page. I run sites where some products will show the rich snippets, while others simply don't. All the markup is the same, but it seems somewhat random.