# Building domain authority for rich snippets

Tags: google, rich-snippets

I recently added breadcrumb and product rich snippets for my site but they are not being displayed in Google's returned search results. My other sites seem to be fine but my eCommerce site's rich snippets just aren't getting picked up.

According to my research the site needs more authority. Does anyone have any experience with this, or any idea on how to build "rich snippet authority"?

Comment: We are getting a lot of questions about rich snippets not showing up in the search results these days.  [See this one for example](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50105/google-rich-snippets-not-showing-in-serp-but-was-detected-in-webmaster-tools).  That question is about why they don't show up, while this question is about how to encourage them.  They are different enough that I'm not going to mark them as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

***Domain authority is basically nothing to do with Rich Snippets Directly***

However some rich snippets work indirectly because they may only display when your within a certain rank on the page and some rich snippets will only display for certain keywords. So if you don't rank for "socks" but your ranked top for "buy socks Bournemouth" then the likelihood is that the rich snippets will not be displayed because of them not being enabled for this term.

Domain authority comes naturally when you start building great content and gain virtual PR through visits, back links, social mentions, and age... the list goes on and on... Your best off
[looking at ways to increase a site position in Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google/1547#1547). Everyone wants to gain domain authority and it's not a simple here 10's things.. It's over a book's worth, but with this said Pro Webmasters has tons of SEO questions and answers, some of the best threads can be found by searching for tags and view in [**seo best votes for example**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=SEO%20is:question).

Comment: Thanks, sure I know all about MOZ DA, I probably should have said something better than "Domain Authority" in the question. I guess I mean Rich Snippet Authority, and is there such a thing, and how to build it up.

Comment: There's no such thing as Rich Snippet Authority as far as I know... As I said Rich Snippets work of certain keywords and placement of the sites on the page, increasing domain authority will improve your rankings which indirectly means you might display more rich snippets. Also don't confuse MOZ DA with Google's DA... It's simply there own matrix how they think Google works.

Comment: in other words build more links

Comment: Nope... They'll likely decrease your rankings for that. Building links is exactly hard these days and the best way is to use bait pages to get people to want to link to your site. Google now profiles sites and its extremely complex... Profiling is like link diversity, simply having one type of links that often are self generated will result in negative SEO.. for example blog comments, forums, directories, infographics etc are all user generated content. Google has a good idea where people can build links.. to many of these links will be negative SEO.

Comment: Build some great content, run a competition, release the best infographic ever... Finding something that people want to link too is the hard part. For example, friend of mine makes house signs.... yes, boring.... then he had a bright idea to make a engraved stone with the royal wedding Kate and William getting married, this got a lot of attention and was linked by some of the top media companies in the country, within a few weeks he was out ranking all of his competition... Fewer links, better links is the best SEO :P All it takes is good brain storming.